# Microsoft Bing Speech API SDK stops listenning after some time

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, bing, azure-cognitive-services

I using [Microsoft Bing Speech API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api) for doing some speech to text tasks. Here's how i did the coding,

```
MicrophoneRecognitionClient micClient;

micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.CreateMicrophoneClient(SpeechRecognitionMode.LongDictation, "en-US", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bingspeechkey"]);

micClient.OnResponseReceived += (s, e) =>
{
};

micClient.StartMicAndRecognition();
```

For some time around 1 minute this works fine. after that it just stops responding. I have no idea what's causing this.

Can anyone give me an idea on fixing this issue?

Comment: What does `it stops responding` mean? Have you defined all handlers? `OnMicrophoneStatus`, `OnPartialResponseReceived`, `OnResponseReceived`, `OnConversationError`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/home), there is a difference between Rest and WebSocket. You have not mentioned which one you are using.

There are also 3 [recognition modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/bingvoicerecognition#recognition-modes). You might want to select the appropriate one out of *interactive*, *dictation* and *conversation*

Please comment if that was the correct ideas or you need more.
(aka, can you get your question more specific?)